# How does fairness policy works in Java thread?

Tags: multithreading, java-8

I am trying to write a program for traditional consumer and producer thread problem using lock.
Following is syntax for the same.

Following example only work fine if I use fairness policy true otherwise it does not provide expected result. It works fine too if I turn on await method for both producer and consumer.
What that means actually, is not possible to produce 1 and consume it without await and fairness policy.

```
public class ProductLockDemo2 {

    private Integer number = 0;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private Condition pCondition = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition cCondition = lock.newCondition();

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {

        if (getNumber() == 10) {
            pCondition.await();
        }
        lock.lock();
        number = number + 1;
        System.out.println("producing number :" + number);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        cCondition.signal();
//      pCondition.await();
        lock.unlock();

    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {

        if (getNumber() == 0) {
            cCondition.await();
        }

        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("consumeing:" + number);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        pCondition.signal();
//      cCondition.await();
        lock.unlock();

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are actually asking here?  How is fairness implemented?  If that is your question you need to download the OpenJDK source code and look for yourself.

Comment: @StephenC, I am asking if I don't pass true to ReentrantLock it means lock without fairness policy and my program does not give expected result. It prints producer value several time and then give access to consumer. This is how lock should work.

Comment: It is hard to say why your code requires `fairness` to be `true` to work.  You haven't provided a complete working example.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  But ... as a general statement ... it is certainly plausible that your code requires this ... and this is NOT evidence of a bug in `ReentrantLock`.

Comment: I'm surprised your code doesn't throw an exception. You're calling `await()` on conditions without first acquiring the lock. That should result in an `IllegalMonitorStateException`. And your `number` field is not properly guarded. You modify it in your producer method after acquiring the lock, indicating it can be concurrently accessed, but then you access it in the getter and setter methods without acquiring the lock. And as noted by David, it makes no sense to `sleep` a thread while holding a lock (doing so doesn't release the lock).

Comment: Also, you should use the `lock.lock(); try { ... } finally { lock.unlock(); }` pattern in order to ensure the lock is released.

Comment: @StephenC, you are correct, I don't need sleep here. Looks I mixes lock approach with traditional thread. Now after removing sleep its working fine. Actually I wanted to have 1 sec delay before consumer consume it so used sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your threads hold the lock, in effect, all of the time. That means that one thread will run for a *long* time before the other thread gets a chance to run.

It's not clear why your program operates this way. Why are you holding a lock while you're sleeping? How are you expecting the other thread to get a chance to run? Why use two threads when there is no possible concurrency because neither thread can get any work done without holding the very same lock the other one needs to get any work done?

If you want strict alternation, you can always write code to force that result. But 99.9% of the time, you don't want that. If you did, why would you use threads? And why would you want the most inefficient possible scheduling policy where you blow out caches and force context switches as often as possible?

Why is your producer holding the lock while it's producing? Why not give the consumer a chance to work?

Tl;DR: You're getting terrible results because you have designed a producer and a consumer that are not capable of operating concurrently at all. The producer should only hold the lock for the split second it needs to pass its results to the consumer and the consumer should only hold the lock for the split second it needs to get work to consume. Neither thread should hold the lock while it's doing any real work or waiting for new work.